# CQ5 - "Server not ready, browser not launched"

Tags: aem

I am running CQ5.4, and I am attempting to set up a local instance. I followed the instructions found on http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-4/howto/installingcq.html, however, my server is not launching. I am getting the following error in my stderr.log file:

```
Exception in shutdown polling thread, giving up: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
Shutdown polling thread ends
Retrying http://localhost:7502/crx (ConnectException) (1/60)...
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.day.commons.httpclient.impl.ProxySelector).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Retrying http://localhost:7502/crx (ConnectException) (3/60)...
```

And then it continues to retry until it quits, and I get the message, "Server not ready, browser not launched." Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like it is crashing after trying to start the "sling" servlet, if that helps. In server.log, this is the last line before a slew of errors:

`23.06.2014 14:58:39 *MARK * webapp-CRX Launchpad Webapp: Start servlet 'sling'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to uninstall java7 before my server would start. I tried opening the jar file with java6, but it didn't work until I had removed java7 from my machine. Make sure you have only java6 version running in your machine. If you have Java 7, try uninstalling that and retry.

Comment: Note that this solution was for 5.4. java7 will probably work with newer versions of CQ.

Comment: Please check your JDK. As per Adobe documentation - http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-4/deploying/technical_requirements.html#Java Virtual Machines, you can use JRE 1.5 or JRE 1.6. JRE 1.7 is not supported. I have seen this issue surfacing when using higher JRE than recommended.